# Shannon Entropy

Tags: c++, entropy

The following C++ code (as is) is from http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Entropy. There are mistakes - can anyone correct them?

```
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cmath>

double log2( double number ) {
    return log( number ) / log( 2 ) ;
}

int main( int argc , char *argv[ ] ) {
    std::string teststring( argv[ 1 ] ) ;
    std::map<char , int> frequencies ;

    for ( char c : teststring )
        frequencies[ c ] ++ ;

    int numlen = teststring.length( ) ;
    double infocontent = 0 ;

    for ( std::pair<char , int> p : frequencies ) {
        double freq = static_cast<double>( p.second ) / numlen ;
        infocontent += freq * log2( freq ) ;
    }

    infocontent *= -1 ;

    std::cout << "The information content of " << teststring 
      << " is " << infocontent << " !\n" ;
    return 0 ;
}
```

The first error seems to be fixed with:

```
double log2( double n )  
{  
    // log(n)/log(2) is log2.  
    return log( n ) / log( 2. );  
}
```

I'm unsure what they are trying to say with:

```
for ( char c : teststring )
```

Comment: The `for` loop is called a "`for each`" loop

Comment: Can you please explain which kind of images you want and about your norm/measures/...? Is L2 sufficient? What is original signal if 1D in the generation? Often, norm is not sufficient. Please, provide other conditions.  - - I think your entropy function cannot be sufficient for studying the entropy of images. It is about 1D signals. I would love to hear why you think your 1D approach and its extension with charactersitcs could be sufficient for images. I see no consideration about measures and bit base. Your source is limited. Related http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/4935/10350 but still a stub.

Comment: What is your goal in using Shannon's entropy for images?

Answer (score 5):

This one work nice

```
template <typename T> static float ShannonEntropy(T data[],int elements){
    float entropy=0;
    std::map<T,long> counts;
    typename std::map<T,long>::iterator it;
    //
    for (int dataIndex = 0; dataIndex < elements; ++dataIndex) {
        counts[data[dataIndex]]++;
    }
    //
    it = counts.begin();
    while(it != counts.end()){
        float p_x = (float)it->second/elements;
        if (p_x>0) entropy-=p_x*log(p_x)/log(2);
        it++;
    }
    return entropy;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The loop is a foreach loop. It means: For each character in teststring, put it into the variable c and do the loop body.

The same can be expressed with a regular for-loop and an index variable, but this way is much shorter and easier to read. Other languages like C# and Java had this for a long time, but C++ only had some template feature in the STL that were not as readable.

This is a new feature of `C++ 11` and your compiler will complain if it's not compatible. If you get errors, try to get a better compiler.

Comment: Thank you, I suspected my compiler. I'm looking for a quick and easy way to calculate the entropy of short (text) DNA strings that form crossing-structure... Learning a new compiler in the middle of my project isn't a very palatable option. Better yet, if someone would point me to some concise code that achieves my purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my java code for entropy of image

```
public static double getShannonEntropy_Image(BufferedImage actualImage){
        List<String> values= new ArrayList<String>();
        int n = 0;
        Map<Integer, Integer> occ = new HashMap<>();
        for(int i=0;i<actualImage.getHeight();i++){
                for(int j=0;j<actualImage.getWidth();j++){
                        int pixel = actualImage.getRGB(j, i);
                        int alpha = (pixel >> 24) & 0xff;
                        int red = (pixel >> 16) & 0xff;
                        int green = (pixel >> 8) & 0xff;
                        int blue = (pixel) & 0xff;
                        //0.2989 * R + 0.5870 * G + 0.1140 * B greyscale conversion
                        //System.out.println("i="+i+" j="+j+" argb: " + alpha + ", " + red + ", " + green + ", " + blue);
                        int d= (int)Math.round(0.2989 * red + 0.5870 * green + 0.1140 * blue);
                        if(!values.contains(String.valueOf(d)))
                                values.add(String.valueOf(d));
                        if (occ.containsKey(d)) {
                                occ.put(d, occ.get(d) + 1);
                        } else {
                                occ.put(d, 1);
                        }
                        ++n;
                }
        }
        double e = 0.0;
        for (Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry : occ.entrySet()) {
                int cx = entry.getKey();
                double p = (double) entry.getValue() / n;
                e += p * log2(p);
        }
        return -e;
}
```

Comment: A sentence or two of explanation goes a long way into making a correct answers and excellent one.

Comment: You code is using an array and HashMap as the data structures. You study the height of the image and loop it - study characteristics as column-wise. Lastly, you loop through the set of characteristics and map features to them with keys and probabilities. You use very simplistic measure of 1D entropy for images. You assume 2 bit signal data too. - - This code cannot be sufficient for studying the entropy in images.

Answer (score 0):

The first error is because of the fiasco regarding names from the C library. It's not specified which overloads of `log` are dumped into the global namespace; presumably, the author's implementation only had one, so that `log(2)` is unambiguous, but yours has all of them, giving an ambiguity since there isn't one that takes type `int`. For portability, it should be `std::log(2.)`. Better still, use `std::log2` rather than reinventing it.

The second is a "range-based `for` statement", introduced to the language in 2011, which iterates over each element of an array, container, or other sequence. You'll need a reasonably modern compiler, and you may need to specifically enable C++11 support. For example, with GCC, you need the command-line argument `-std=c++11` (or `c++0x` with older versions).

Answer (score 0):

The above generic answer is very good, but for the particular case of strings, this one is simpler:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <string>
float shannon_entropy(const std::string & s)
{
    int counts[256] = {};
    for (unsigned char c: s)
    {
        counts[c]++;
    }

    float entropy = 0;
    float length = (float)s.size();
    for (int count: counts)
    {
        if (count == 0)
            continue;
        float p = (float)count / length;
        entropy -= p * std::log2f(p);
    }
    return entropy;
}
```